# Does Google Translation API charge for Language Detection and Translation separately if Source Language is not passed?

Tags: google-translate, google-translation-api

I am using Google Translation Advanced using Golang Client. I see that the input param, `SourceLanguageCode` is optional. I have confirmed that if we don't pass the `SourceLanguageCode`, the API still returns the result as expected. But when I don't pass the `SourceLanguageCode`, does the API call get charged both for Language Detection and Translation?

I looked at the Pricing page and this part is not described clearly: https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing

I have an option of finding the `SourceLanguageCode` from a different library, so I would pass the `SourceLanguageCode` as an input param if Google Translate charges me twice the amount for every API call if that is not passed.

But, if Google Translate doesn't charge for Language Detection separately for Translation, I would rather let Google decide the source language automatically.

For reference, this is how I am getting the `translatedText` and `detectedLanguage` from the Golang client:

**Package:** https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/genproto@v0.0.0-20210813162853-db860fec028c/googleapis/cloud/translate/v3?utm_source=gopls#Translation

**Example:** https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/translating-text-v3#translating_input_strings

**My code:**

```
for _, translation := range resp.GetTranslations() {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Translated text: %v\n", translation.GetTranslatedText())
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Detected language: %v\n", translation.DetectedLanguageCode())
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This sounds more like a customer support/billing question than a programming one.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Agreed that it is more of a billing question, I put it here in case anyone who is using the Translation API would have an answer. I added the code just to highlight if invoking `DetectedLanguageCode()` on the translation object separately for returning the detected language code has any effect on the billing as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pricing link answers the question that we will be only charged once even if we don't specify the source language: https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing

> You are only charged for the text that you provided; there's no
> additional charge for the detection in addition to the translation.
> For example, if you submit 1,000 characters for translation without
> specifying the source language, you are only charged for the 1,000
> characters.